# React useEffect with auth0 is not working for getAccessTokenSilently as expected

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have the following React component which i based on this [documentation on Auth0 Website](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0-react?utm_source=emea-google-dg&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=Branded&utm_content=dynamicRT1&utm_term=&gclid=EAIaIQobChMI-6Ll-5O26wIVgtCyCh0osQ4CEAAYASAAEgJ3kvD_BwE#call-an-api)

here is my code i ommited some unrelated lines

```
import * as Auth0 from "@auth0/auth0-react";
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactRedux from 'react-redux';

interface IProps{.....}
const AppComponent: React.SFC<IProps> = (props) => {

   const { getAccessTokenSilently } = Auth0.useAuth0();
   React.useEffect(() => {
     (async () => {
      try{
       const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
       console.log(token);
       Props.setAccessToken(token); // this is a dispatch to save the token into redux state
      }
      catch(error){console.log(error);}
     })();
   }, [getAccessTokenSilently]);

   return(
   <> /*some jsx */ </>
   );
}

const mapDispatchToProps //standard redux mapping 
const mapStateToProps // standard redux mapping

export default ReactRedux.connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(AppComponent);
```

the behavior i am getting is that once the component renders it logs the token to the console however after the token expiry the useffect is not happening to get a new token which is what i am trying to achieve any idea what could be wrong or if there is a better way to achieve the result of updating access token on expiry with out it being tightly coupled to specific action.

Edit1: i missed adding that having the token refreshed on intervals is not possible this would ship as a whole product for different clients and each client has their own Auht0 tenant i cannot assume a specific token life span

Answer (score 0):

I use a hook I made called `useInterval` to update the token in the background at specific intervals.

`useInterval.ts`

```
import { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";

export const useInterval = (func: () => void, delay: number, startImmediately: boolean, funcDeps: React.DependencyList) => {
    const callback = useCallback(func, funcDeps);

    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = setInterval(callback, delay);
        startImmediately && callback();
        return () => clearInterval(handler);
    }, [callback, delay, startImmediately]);
}
```

Usage in app component

```
useInterval(() => {
    // code to update access token
}, 300000, true, [dependencies]);
```

Comment: i am trying to avoid intervals as this app would deploy for different clients and each client would have their own access token life time span and i cannot expect users to know the life time

Comment: You could set the interval based on the token expiration and have it be dynamic.

Comment: that is worth a shot i will test and let you know

Comment: just to update setting up dynamic intervals turned out to be tricky ordeal so for now i ignored this item, however if you would continue your help and show me an example with a dynamic intervals coming from the token i would be grateful